# How to extract YYYY-mm-dd from date string?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have date in format `2017-08-24 22:22:45`. How to extract only `2017-08-24`?

I tried to use:

```
var data = date.Split('-');
string convertedDate = data[0] + date[1] + date[2];
```

But I dislike this solution/

Comment: Something like [ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) and then cut the time part

Comment: string formatted = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

Comment: `data.Substring(0,10)`?

Comment: how about `date.SubString(0, 10);`?

Comment: @Ankit But it's a string not a `DateTime`.

Comment: I tried, can not convert to string:  string result = DateTime.ParseExact(date, format, provider);

Comment: @OPV `ParseExact`  return a `DateTime`

Comment: @litelite If the input is a string and the output needs to be a string there's no point in parsing it if the format is known.  Now you could make the argument that the OP should be working with `DateTime` to begin with, but that's out of scope.

Comment: FYI your current solution doesn't extract "YYYY-mm-dd", but instead "YYYYmmdd" without the dashes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
DateTime s = DateTime.Parse("2017-08-24 22:22:45");
Console.WriteLine(s.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

More datetime .ToString() formats 
https://blog.nicholasrogoff.com/2012/05/05/c-datetime-tostring-formats-quick-reference/

Comment: Also once you've parsed to a datetime if you are only interested in the date portion but want to keep working with a date structure, you can always call the Date property: `DateTime.Now.Date` to truncate the time portion of the structure.

Answer (score 2):

Other option could be:

```
string date = "2017-08-24 22:22:45"; 
string convertedDate = date.Split(' ')[0];

// Result: 2017-08-24
```

Answer (score 2):

if  Date:

```
string convertedDate = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

if String:

```
string convertedDate = data.Substring(0,10);
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply:

```
var convertedDate = date.Substring(0, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your string can be converted into a DateTime object then you can use however you want.

```
string dateStr = "2017-08-24 22:22:45";

DateTime date = DateTime.Now;

if(DateTime.TryParse(dateStr, out date))
    Console.Write(date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using** `ParseExact`

```
var strDate = "2017-08-24 22:22:45";
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine("Your date "+ myDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Regular Expression pattern:

```
var src = "2017-08-24 22:22:45";
var pattern = @"^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}";

var ans = Regex.Match(src, pattern).Value;
```

But that is probably overkill - just extract it:

```
var ans = src.Substring(0, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for you,

`string date = "2017-08-24 22:22:45"; 
string convertedDate = date.Split(' ')[0];`

Comment: `string.Split()` returns an array, not a string.